# Installing Ubuntu on external HDD from windows 10

Tags: 18.04

I have been trying to install Ubuntu onto a 150gb Hitachi external HDD. For some reason I always get an error when I follow guides online. I have gotten it to install onto the drive a few times but then it won't boot. So, can I juts have exact instructions on how to install Ubuntu 18.04 into an USB 3.0 external HDD.

Thanks, 
Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Burn ubuntu desktop dvd, or make usb flash install media. Detach internal hdd and attach both install media and external hdd. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd> or something else what displayed for activate boot menu when booting, and choose install media. Install Ubuntu to external hdd.

Power off and connect internal hdd.

This way you'll be able to choose external hdd to boot. Or you can edit bios and make usb hdd highest priority to boot so it will boot every time it connected, if not connected internal hdd should take it place.

Comment: I understand how to make the usb installer. What I'm having trouble with is after I click something else and how to partition the drive.

Comment: UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu  Ubutu now uses a swap file, so no swap partition required. If dual booting in UEFI mode, Ubuntu will use existing ESP and add another folder for /EFI/ubuntu next to the Windows folder.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Comment: That's why I considered detach internal hdd, to not use internal hdd uefi for removable media. @AnthonyPerry make gpt and one full disk partition on removable hdd, fs is ext4. or choose to use full disk and everything will be done for you.